# make <sections> stay in place when shrinking window

Tags: css

I have two boxes inside my `<header>-tag`, which has a total width of 100%. When i align them up they fit perfect, but when i'm shrinking the window the right box jumps down beneath the left one. Here's the code:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
}

#head {
  float: left;
  background-image: url('img/header.jpg');
  height: 120px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 65%;
}

#userinfo {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 33.2%;
  background-color: #202020;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <section id="head">
  </section>
  <section id="userinfo">
    test
  </section>
</header>
```

Any quick fixes? Imagining this happens with the rest of my design as I'm moving forward. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We'll need the rest of the code, especially the markup

Comment: Sorry, updated! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are using some values for `padding` and `margin` on your elements and those by default are added to the actual size of the element, since both elements are `98.2%` of the container `+20` of the values at some point they don't fit into the 100% and will break.

To solve it you can use `box-sizing` property which will make the `padding` and `border` values be inside the total declared size, and since that doesn't work with `margin` you will need an extra container to use `padding` and create the separation:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
}

#head {
  float: left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 65%;
}
#head > div {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500');
  height: 120px;
}

#userinfo {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 35%;
  background-color: #202020;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <section id="head">
    <div></div>
  </section>
  <section id="userinfo">
    test
  </section>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks DaniP, that solved it. But what about the content and sidebars part then?:

```
#container {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 400px;
}

#leftmenu {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: #202020;
}

#content {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #202020;
  min-height: 600px;
}

#content > div {
  background-color: #202020;
  min-height: 600px;
}

#rightmenu {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: #202020;
}
```

Comment: Hi I haven't seen this post is better if you reply with a comment on my answer  that way I can be notified. Can you clarify what is the issue now ?